# Importing module from function in __init__.py binds module object to global namespace?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I'm a beginner to Python, and I have a doubt about how module objects are bound to the package's `__init__.py` namespace.
I'll state the problem more clearly with some code.

---

Suppose to have a package called `myPkg`, containing two modules: `firstMod` and `secondMod`:

```
myPkg\
     __init__.py
     firstMod.py
     secondMod.py
```

The file `__init__.py` is the following:

```
def myFun():
    from . import firstMod as fm

myFun()
```

The file `firstMod` is empty.

The file `secondMod` is the following:

```
def myFun():
    from . import firstMod as fm

myFun()
```

---

Now, run the Python 2.7.15 interpreter in the same directory as `myPkg`, and do the following:

```
>>> import myPkg
>>> dir(myPkg)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'firstMod', 'myFun']
>>> from myPkg import secondMod
>>> dir(secondMod)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'myFun']
>>>
```

---

While the result of `dir(secondMod)` was expected, the result of `dir(myPkg)` was unexpected (to me). It seems that, just for the package's `__init__.py` module, the names of the imported module objects are bound to the global namespace even if the modules are imported from whithin a function. This does not occur in other modules.

Edit: as it turns out, this only happens when importing modules of the package. Importing external modules from `myFun` does not result in name binding in `__init__.py`.

---

Can anyone explain why this happens?
And also: is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

---

### Edit

Note that the presence of `'firstMod'` in the global namespace of `__init__.py` is a property that applies only to packages.

In fact, if one defines two modules:

```
zeroMod.py
firstMod.py
```

outside of any package, and fills `zeroMod.py` with:

```
def myFun():
    import firstMod as fm

myFun()
```

the interpreter won't bind the name `'firstMod'` to the global namespace of `zeroMod.py`, even if `firstMod.py` is loaded for the first time:

```
>>> import zeroMod
>>> dir(zeroMod)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'myFun']
>>>
```

I don't understand why the name binding occurs for `__init__.py` but not for `zeroMod.py`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run:

```
import myPkg
```

Python will load the file `myPkg/__init__.py` and execute it.

Since, this package contains a function call (`myFun()`), it will execute it (only once at first import).

The `myFun()` is:

```
def myFun():
    from . import firstMod as fm
```

Again, this function imports the `firstMod`. So the file `myPkg/firstMod.py` is loaded and executed (nothing is done because `firstMod.py` is empty).

At the end of `myPkg` import, you get the following object at module level:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'firstMod', 'myFun']
```

Then, in the same Python session, if you run:

```
from myPkg import secondMod
```

Python will not load the file `myPkg/__init__.py` a second time, because the module is already loaded.

Python will load the file `myPkg/secondMod.py` and execute it.

This package contains another function call (`myFun()`), it will execute it too. Note that you use the same name but in different namespaces, so the two `myFun()` functions are different.

The `myFun()` import `firstMod` too:

```
def myFun():
    from . import firstMod as fm
```

The `firstMod` is already imported, so you won't find it in your `secondMod` module:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'myFun']
```

Things you should consider:

- you should consider following the [PEP8 naming conventions](https://pep8.org/#naming-conventions).
- Modules are singleton (even if in some rare case you can re-load a module),
- If you don't want to run code in your module, use the classic approach:

For instance:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    myFun()
```

Comment: Hello Laurent, and thank you for your answer. However, I'm not finding an answer to the actual problem of the described behaviour occurring for \_\_init\_\_.py, but not for any other module. It seems that this behaviour has nothing to do with the fact that firstMod.py is imported for the first time or not. Take a look to the edit.